# Print everything after a grep?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I got a really big logcat (since 2016) and I'm interested in printing everything (all the rows) after a point (let's say, September). The logcat is really big, so I can't really use tail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print everything after matching a "needle", using sed:

```
sed -n '/needle/,$p' filename
```

Replace `needle` with the actual pattern you witch to match at which point in the file to being printing.

Comment: `sed -n '/needle/,$p'` if you don't want to stop at the second needle.

Comment: There won't be a second needle because I use timestamps. Thanks a lot!